# UI View Controller is not updated when using VIPER Architecture

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

So, I am new to VIPER and have built simple demo app of http request using the architecture. I got an issue where the UI are not updated although the the method within the view is still called because I have checked that the print("test") is executed and shown on the debug console. This is the relevant code:

View :

```
  private func getAllContacts(){
        self.contacts = []
        self.hud.show(in: self.view)
        self.presenter?.fetchListContacts()
        print("asd")
        
    }
```

Presenter :

```
  func fetchListContacts(){
        print("sdf")
        interactor?.getContacts()
    }
```

Interactor :

```
   func getContacts(){
        print("123")
        var contacts : [DetailContact] = []
        contacts = \\APICALL
        self.presenter?.listContactFetchSuccess(contacts)
           }
```

Baxk to PResenter :

```
 func listContactFetchSuccess(_ contacts: [DetailContact]) {
        print("gxx")
        view?.fetchSucceed(contacts: contacts)
    }
```

back to View :

```
     func fetchSucceed(contacts: [DetailContact]) {
        self.contacts = contacts
        self.hud.dismiss()
        self.contactTableView.reloadData()
        print("test")
    }
```

My Router :

```
  static func createListContactModule() -> ListViewController {
        let view = mainstoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListViewController") as! ListViewController
        
        var presenter: ViewToPresenterListProtocol & InteractorToPresenterListProtocol = ListContactPresenter()
        var interactor: PresenterToInteractorListProtocol = ListContactInteractor()
        let router:PresenterToRouterListProtocol = ListContactRouter()
        
        view.presenter = presenter
        presenter.view = view
        presenter.router = router
        presenter.interactor = interactor
        interactor.presenter = presenter
        
        return view
    }
```

Comment: Is the contact list getting updated "contacts" can you add a breakpoint and check?
I think "self.presenter?.listContactFetchSuccess(contacts)" this part of the code should be in the completion of the API call.

Comment: @Let's_Create yeah I have double cross-checked, that the value of the contacts is there, and have been passed back to my view controller. I have tried adding the breakpoint and my fetchSucceed function in View and indeed the function has been called with the contacts data passed from the presenter and interactor. I have checked the contacts data on debug console log within the view controller using the print command

Answer (score 0):

The progress hud at least closes? or does not suffer any change?

I suggest you put the content of your function `fetchSucceed(contacts: [DetailContact])` into the main queue like:

```
func fetchSucceed(contacts: [DetailContact]) {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.contacts = contacts
        self.hud.dismiss()
        self.contactTableView.reloadData()
        print("test")
     }
}
```

Maybe the API call that you use, is changing the thread of the excecution therefore your UI calls are not showing, because it always must be excecuted in the main thread.